# How are site-creation services built?

Tags: design, architecture, web-development

I have always wondered how sites like Blogger, Wordpress.com, Forumotion, Jcink or Forumatic (shut down) work but I can't seem to grasp an idea about how they're internally made.

At first sight they all work the same way, they allow users to create a new site (under their domain) using any popular software. Let's take for example the case of Forumatic. Forumatic allowed users to create phpBB (a open source forum software built with PHP) sites.

I guess that the phpBB codebase is not duplicated every time a user creates a new site, because the code is common for every forum. The only need that changes is, for example, the config file which would need, among other things, to link to a specific database for the created forum.

The point of my question is. How all of this is built? Any idea about the architecture of this kind of systems? Any special cases to be aware of?

Comment: Think of each “tenant” site as an account in the given ecosystem rather than in an OS. There is an underlying database which holds all the info for each site.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess that the phpBB codebase is not duplicated every time a user creates a new site

It is actually very often the case, especially when you open an account with open source software like phpBB, Wordpress etc installed. Each user has its own isolated codebase and database.

Blogger on the other hand is a Google platform, it is not open sourced project, so internally they most likely have just one system/platform which runs for every user. Of course it is distributed and architecture could be complicated.

If you want to build such system, you need to start with basic platform which should have multi-domain support, where one domain is linked to one account, and each account has its admin (or admins) and users/subscribers/etc.